# Calling Stop() on an Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool thows 'NotImplementedException'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

```
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.ExecuteMethod(String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ApplicationPool.Stop()
   at MyFileManagerService.RemoveWebService(String accountName, Int32 siteId)
```

Im going by these docs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.stop?view=iis-dotnet

How can I stop the AppPool if the method is not implemented?

This is a  asp.net core 3.1 app built in c#.

edit:  This is weird, even checking the AppPool.State throws the same exception.

Comment: That documentation assumes you use MWA API in a .NET Framework application. More in https://blog.lextudio.com/whats-microsoft-web-administration-and-the-horrible-facts-you-should-know-b82f2c974da6 An ASP.NET Core application should not attempt to use that API.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the library is not fully implemented in .NET Core. The same code would work .NET 4.8 probably.

Comment: My previous statement was wrong. It works as expected, but not during debugging in visual studio (even if running as administrator). If the application runs standalone or in IIS it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,please ensure you are importing the Microsoft.web.administration via microsoft nuget manager.

If you want to stop IIS application pool, then please deploy the asp.net core app to your local IIS. Otherwise, it will try to load profile from IIS express instead of IIS.

Finally, please try to change application pool identity to Local system. Otherwise, default IIS app pool identity will never have permission to stop app pool.